# Java Tetris Key Listener Not Working (No Errors On Console)

Tags: java

I'm working on a project for my AP computer science class and can't seem to figure out how to get my key listeners to work I've tried using if statements and switch cases but neither of these make the key listeners work. The code consists of three classes  Tetris Runner, Canvas, PeiceMaker everything functions fine with exception of the key listeners The key listeners are located at the bottom of the canvas class any help would be appreciated thanks.

Canvas Class

```
    package Tetris;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import Tetris.PieceMaker.Tetronimos;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Canvas extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    public static final int CANVASWIDTH = 10;
    public static final int CANVASHEIGHT = 22;

    private Color[] colors = 
    {
            new Color(0, 0, 0),
            new Color(204, 102, 102),
            new Color(102, 204, 102),
            new Color(102, 102, 204),
            new Color(204, 204, 102),
            new Color(204, 102, 204), 
            new Color(102, 204, 204), 
            new Color(218, 170, 0)
    };

    private boolean blockSet = false;
    private boolean startGame = false; 
    private boolean pauseGame = false;
    private int linesErased = 0;
    private int currentX = 0;
    private int currentY = 0;

    private JLabel scoreLabel;

    private Timer time;

    private PieceMaker currentShape;
    private Tetronimos[] canvas;

    public Canvas(TetrisRunner run)
    {
        setFocusable(true);
        currentShape = new PieceMaker();
        time = new Timer(500, this);
        scoreLabel = run.getScoreLabel();
        canvas = new Tetronimos[CANVASWIDTH * CANVASHEIGHT];
        clearCanvas();
        addKeyListener(new TetrisAdap());
    }

    public int blockWidth()
    {
        return (int)getSize().getWidth()/CANVASWIDTH;
    }

    public int blockHeight()
    {
        return (int)getSize().getHeight()/CANVASHEIGHT;
    }

    public Tetronimos shapeLocation(int x, int y)
    {
        return canvas[y * CANVASWIDTH + x];
    }

    public void clearCanvas()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < CANVASHEIGHT * CANVASWIDTH; i++)
        {
            canvas[i] = Tetronimos.noShape;
        }
    }

    public void droppedPiece()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int newX = currentX + currentShape.getXPosition(i);
            int newY = currentY - currentShape.getYPosition(i);

            canvas[newY * CANVASWIDTH + newX] = currentShape.getShape();
        }

        clearRow();

        if(!blockSet)
        {
            makeNewPiece();
        }
    }

    public void makeNewPiece()
    {
        currentShape.chooseRandomShape();

        currentX = CANVASWIDTH / 2 + 1;
        currentY = CANVASHEIGHT - 1 + currentShape.minY();

        if(!movePiece(currentShape, currentX, currentY - 1))
        {
            currentShape.setShape(Tetronimos.noShape);
            time.stop();

            startGame = false;
            scoreLabel.setText("GAME OVER");
        }
    }

    public void moveDownLine()
    {
        if(!movePiece(currentShape, currentX, currentY - 1))
        {
            droppedPiece();
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if(blockSet)
        {
            blockSet = false;
            makeNewPiece();
        } else {
            moveDownLine();
        }
    }

    public void drawShape(int x, int y, Tetronimos shape, Graphics g)
    {
        Color color = colors[shape.ordinal()];
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, blockWidth() - 2, blockHeight() - 2);
        g.setColor(color.brighter());
        g.drawLine(x, y + blockHeight() - 1, x, y);
        g.drawLine(x, y, x + blockWidth() - 1, y);
        g.setColor(color.darker());
        g.drawLine(x + 1, y + blockHeight() - 1, x + blockWidth() - 1, y + blockHeight() - 1);
        g.drawLine(x + blockWidth() - 1, y + blockHeight() - 1, x + blockWidth() - 1, y + 1);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        Dimension size = getSize();

        int topOfCanvas = (int)size.getHeight() - CANVASHEIGHT * blockHeight();

        for(int i = 0; i < CANVASHEIGHT; i++)
        {
            for(int p = 0; p < CANVASWIDTH; p++)
            {
                Tetronimos shape = shapeLocation(p, CANVASHEIGHT - i - 1);

                if(shape != Tetronimos.noShape)
                {
                    drawShape(p * blockWidth(), topOfCanvas + i * blockHeight(), shape, g);
                }
            }
        }

        if(currentShape.getShape() != Tetronimos.noShape)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
            {
                int x  = currentX + currentShape.getXPosition(i);
                int y = currentY - currentShape.getYPosition(i);

                drawShape(x * blockWidth(), topOfCanvas + (CANVASHEIGHT - y - 1) * blockHeight(), currentShape.getShape(), g);
            }
        }
    }

    public void start()
    {
        if(pauseGame)
        {
            return;
        }

        startGame = true;
        blockSet = false;
        linesErased = 0;

        clearCanvas();
        makeNewPiece();
        time.start();
    }

    public void pause()
    {
        if(!startGame)
        {
            return;
        }

        pauseGame = !pauseGame;

        if(pauseGame)
        {
            time.stop();
            scoreLabel.setText("PAUSED");
        } else {
            time.start();
            scoreLabel.setText(String.valueOf(linesErased));
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public boolean movePiece(PieceMaker newPiece, int xVel, int yVel)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int x = xVel + newPiece.getXPosition(i);
            int y = yVel - newPiece.getYPosition(i);

            if(x < 0 || x >= CANVASWIDTH || y < 0 || y >= CANVASHEIGHT)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if(shapeLocation(x, y) != Tetronimos.noShape)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        currentShape = newPiece;
        currentX = xVel;
        currentY = yVel;

        repaint();

        return true;
    }



    public void clearRow()
    {
        int fullRows = 0;

        for(int i = CANVASHEIGHT - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            boolean rowIsFull = true;

            for(int p = 0; p < CANVASWIDTH; p++)
            {
                if(shapeLocation(p, i) == Tetronimos.noShape)
                {
                    rowIsFull = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(rowIsFull)
            {
                fullRows++;

                for(int j = i; j < CANVASHEIGHT - 1; j++)
                {
                    for(int k = 0; k < CANVASWIDTH; k++)
                    {
                        canvas[j * CANVASWIDTH + k] = shapeLocation(j, k + 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            if(fullRows > 0)
            {
                linesErased += fullRows;
                scoreLabel.setText(String.valueOf(linesErased));
                blockSet = true;
                currentShape.setShape(Tetronimos.noShape);

                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    public void dropRows()
    {
        int nextY = currentY;

        while(nextY > 0)
        {
            if(!movePiece(currentShape, currentX, nextY - 1))
            {
                break;
            }
            nextY--;    
        }
        droppedPiece();
    }





    //Tetris Adapter

public class TetrisAdap extends KeyAdapter {

        public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
        {
            if(!startGame || currentShape.getShape() == Tetronimos.noShape) 
            {
                System.out.println("Here");
                return;
            }

        int keyCode = ke.getKeyCode();

        if(keyCode == 'p' || keyCode == 'P')
            pause();

        if(pauseGame)
            return;
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) 
        {
            System.out.println("left");
            movePiece(currentShape, currentX - 1, currentY);
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            System.out.println("right");
            movePiece(currentShape, currentX + 1, currentY);
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) 
        {
            System.out.println("down");
            movePiece(currentShape.rotateRight(), currentX, currentY);
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            System.out.println("up");
            movePiece(currentShape.rotateLeft(), currentX, currentY);   
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) 
        {
            dropRows();
        }

        if(keyCode == 'd')
            moveDownLine();

        if(keyCode == 'D')
            moveDownLine();

        /*
         * switch(keyCode) 
        {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                System.out.println("left");
                movePiece(currentShape, currentX - 1, currentY);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                System.out.println("right");
                movePiece(currentShape, currentX + 1, currentY);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                System.out.println("down");
                movePiece(currentShape.rotateRight(), currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                System.out.println("up");
                movePiece(currentShape.rotateLeft(), currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                dropRows();
                break;                  
            case 'd' :
                moveDownLine();
                break;
            case 'D' :
                moveDownLine();
        }
         * 
         */

    }   

}
}
```

Tetris Runner

```
    package Tetris;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TetrisRunner extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel scoreLabel;

    public TetrisRunner()
    {
        scoreLabel = new JLabel("0");
        add(scoreLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(this);
        add(canvas);

        canvas.makeNewPiece();
        canvas.start();

        setSize(400, 800);
        setTitle("Tetris");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TetrisRunner runner = new TetrisRunner();
        runner.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        runner.setVisible(true);    
    }

    public JLabel getScoreLabel()
    {
        return scoreLabel;
    }
}
```

Peice Maker

```
package Tetris;

import java.util.Random;

public class PieceMaker 
{
    private Tetronimos shapeChoice;
    private int[][] coordinates;

    public PieceMaker()
    {
        coordinates = new int[4][2];
        setShape(Tetronimos.noShape);
    }

    enum Tetronimos 
    {
        noShape(new int[][] { {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0} }),
        lineShape(new int[][] { {0,-1}, {0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2} }),
        sShape(new int[][] { {0,-1}, {0,0}, {1,0}, {1,1} }),
        zShape(new int[][] { {0,-1}, {0,0}, {-1,0}, {-1,1} }),
        tShape(new int[][] { {-1,0}, {0,0}, {1,0}, {0,1} }),
        lShape(new int[][] { {-1,-1}, {0,-1}, {0,0}, {0,1} }),
        jShape(new int[][] { {-1,-1}, {0,-1}, {0,0}, {0,1} }),
        blockShape(new int[][] { {0,0}, {1,0}, {0,1}, {1,1} });

        public int[][] shapeCoordinates;

        private Tetronimos(int[][] coordinates)
        {
            this.shapeCoordinates = coordinates;
        }
    }

    public void chooseRandomShape()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randChoice = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 7 + 1);

        Tetronimos[] choice = Tetronimos.values();
        setShape(choice[randChoice]);
    }

    public void setShape(Tetronimos shape)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for(int p = 0; p < 2; p++)
            {
                coordinates[i][p] = shape.shapeCoordinates[i][p];
            }
        }

        shapeChoice = shape;
    }

    public void setXPosition(int oldX, int newX)
    {
        coordinates[oldX][0] = newX;
    }

    public void setYPosition(int oldY, int newY)
    {
        coordinates[oldY][1] = newY;
    }

    public int getXPosition(int newX)
    {
        return coordinates[newX][0];
    }

    public int getYPosition(int newY)
    {
        return coordinates[newY][1];
    }

    public Tetronimos getShape()
    {
        return shapeChoice;
    }

    public int minX()
    {
        int minX = coordinates[0][0];

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            minX = Math.min(minX, coordinates[i][0]);
        }

        return minX;
    }

    public int minY()
    {
        int minY = coordinates[0][1];

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            minY = Math.min(minY, coordinates[i][1]);
        }

        return minY;
    }


    //Rotate piece Left
    public PieceMaker rotateLeft() 
    {
        System.out.println("left");
        if(shapeChoice == Tetronimos.blockShape)
        {
            return this;
        }

        PieceMaker res = new PieceMaker();
        res.shapeChoice = shapeChoice;

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        {
            res.setXPosition(i, getYPosition(i));
            res.setYPosition(i, -getXPosition(i));
        }
        return res;     
    }

    //Rotate piece right
    public PieceMaker rotateRight() 
    {
        System.out.println("right");
        if(shapeChoice == Tetronimos.blockShape)
        {
            return this;
        }
        PieceMaker res = new PieceMaker();
        res.shapeChoice = shapeChoice;


        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        {
            res.setXPosition(i, -getYPosition(i));
            res.setYPosition(i, getXPosition(i));   
        }
        return res; 
    }
}
```

Comment: There is far too much code here.  Please remove all but the 10-20 lines that are causing your issue.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled your keyPressed()-Method. Use

```
public class TetrisAdap extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) { ...
```

instead of

```
public class TetrisAdap extends KeyAdapter {

    public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
    {
```